# Oscillator circuits operation?

Tags: analog, ac, oscillator

Damped AC oscillations are produced in LC circuit by charging and discharging of capacitor and inductor but how it is achieved through an RC circuit as RC circuit is used in Colpitts Oscillator?

Comment: An RC circuit isn't used in the Colpitt's oscillator!

Comment: +1 @Leon's comment. See my answer for why you might be confused about this topic. Cheers.

Comment: RC circuit is used in Phase-shift oscillator. Is this RC circuit produced oscillations like LC circuit?

Answer (score 4):

> The Colpitts circuit, like other LC oscillators, consists of a gain
>   device, such as a transistor or vacuum tube, with its output connected
>   to its input in a feedback loop containing a parallel LC circuit
>   (tuned circuit) which functions as a bandpass filter to set the
>   frequency of oscillation.
>   --[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colpitts_oscillator)

This is a Colpitts' oscillator (most common form; there are several):

[image]

I think you are being confused by the bias resistors. They do not play a role in the AC (oscillating) operation of the circuit (to the first order).

Here it is again with the biasing removed/simplified:

[image]

The oscillator works by applying amplification (positive feedback) via the transistor and using an LC circuit as a filter to set the frequency of oscillation. There are no RC interactions in the ideal case.

Answer (score 2):

In a LC circuit the energy can slosh back and forth between the inductor and capacitor.  Such a circuit does not oscillate on its own, but usually acts as a notch filter within a larger oscillator circuit to dictate the frequency of the oscillations.  Note that a ideal inductor and capacitor in parallel can in theory store energy indefinitely, constantly sloshing it back and forth between the inductor and capacitor at the resonant frequency.

Any circuit with a resistor in it will dissipate power.  RL and RC circuits do not resonate.  Any energy supplied to a resistor is always turned into heat and not recovered into the circuit.  RL and RC circuits can be used to realize filters, but these filters have a single rolloff, not a notch.  They pass below or above the rolloff frequency while attenuating at 20 dB/decade on the other side.

This doesn't directly answer your question since your question doesn't actually make sense.  Neither RL, RC, or LC combinations "produce" AC.  They can pass or block, and in the case of LC store, AC depending on the frequency.

Comment: @ Olin I made a mistake in question which I have edited. Ac signals can be produced using Dc current throgh LC circuit. But we also use RC circuit for same purpose. How is RC circuit is used to produce AC signals. That is my point.

Comment: @Ali: No, AC signals aren't produced by running DC current thru a inductor and capacitor.  Even for a perfect LC, it takes some sort of transient, meaning a changing condition, meaning definitely not DC, to get it ringing.  Any real LC will lose a little energy each cycle, so this ringing will decay in amplitude over time.

Comment: LC circuit produced damped oscillations because of loses in circuit. If we consider it ideally it's oscillation amplitude should increase infinitely or maintained at some fixed amplitude?

Comment: Without the addition of additional energy, it will maintain amplitude in the ideal case. You can evaluate this abstractly by considering that increasing voltages to infinity would reduce currents to 0 resulting in no oscillation.

Answer (score 2):

An oscillator that has insufficient gain will produce a damped waveform.  But, like the original LC circuit, it has to be pulled out of balance and let go--just like plucking a string.

It just so happens that I was trying to model an RC oscillator and it didn't want to oscillate, so I arranged to give it an impulse to see how it behaved.

[image: Twin-T Oscillator Schematic]

SW1 opens shortly after the simulation starts, just like "plucking the string".  You can see the results in this plot:

[image: damped oscillating waveform]

The rate at which the oscillations die out is an indication of how much gain (or loss) is present in the feedback loop.

In your original example, charging a capacitor and placing it across an inductor resulted in the same behavior.  In that circuit there was no amplifier, so its gain had to be less than 1, and so its oscillations naturally died out.   In my case, I just designed my oscillator poorly :)

Answer (score 0):

For a circuit to continuously oscillate at a certain frequency *f*, there must be a feedback loop whose delay is equal to *n/f* for some positive integer *n*, and whose gain is at least 1 (in practice, to avoid having the oscillation amplitude grow endlessly, the gain must be exactly one; this is generally realized by having the gain decrease as amplitude increases).

The delay induced by any single LC or RC circuit (with non-zero R) at frequency *f* is always less than 1/2*f*, and the gain is always less than one.  Consequently, to design an oscillator with just LC or RC circuits and a relatively-linear amplifier would generally require cascading at least three such circuits along with an amplifier that has enough gain to make up for their losses.

Note, btw, that things like relaxation oscillators obey the same rules as other types, but they contain one or more circuit elements whose gain and delay vary enormously (often by orders of magnitude) during each cycle; generally, they vary between values which would be below what's required for stable oscillation at some frequency and values that would be above what's required.  In many cases, such variations in gain will be sufficiently large that it's easier to regard the gain as infinite (and then use different analytical techniques which use that assumption) than apply the techniques that would be used with oscillators built from linear circuits.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most revealing type of colpitts oscillator is this: -

[image]

Although the collector has a resistor the actual circuit doesn't rely on the collector at all and in fact this resistor (R4) can be shorted and the circuit still oscillates.

Feedback is from emitter to base and there is actual voltage gain. Some folk may be surprised by this - there is no actual voltage gain at the emitter of a BJT as everyone knows but it is the parallel tuned circuit of L1 and (C1+C2) that dispences voltage gain.

If the emitter injects a signal into the junction of C1 and C2 at the resonant frequency of the tuned circuit, the voltage at the base-end of C1 will be greater than the voltage at the emitter. This circuit easily oscillates without any need to worry about the collector providing voltage gain.

I use it in a lot of VCO circuits ranging from 20MHz up to 400MHz.